# How to Find Desired Enumeration via Jazz Queries?

Tags: httpwebrequest, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz, oslc

I need to either be able to obtain the list of options (with text values) for an enumeration and/or to search for the enumeration/url by a particular value. I can't seem to do either. To obtain the links to users I was able to query work items for a contributor whose name matched my input and thus get the link (as seen below), but I can't seem to do that with the enumerations. It's claiming my rtc_ext:assetType doesn't exist even though I know it does as I'm pulling the name right out of the rdf returned by a work item. What is the proper way to get the enum I'm looking for?

I've found, for the enumerations specifically (not for people), I can get the list of ALL enumeration resources without query. If one item was at http:///stuff/assetType/assetType.literal.l42, I can simply request http:///stuff/assetType/ to get the full list. Unfortunately, my enumeration returns some 326 options and all of which are simply resource urls that I then need to request individually just to determine which one's dc:title == MyValue. I can't seem to query it in any meaningful way to return ONLY the one that has a particular value for dc:title.

**Works for people but not ideal since they must have once been assigned something first:**
`https://<host>/ccm/oslc/contexts/<keything>/workitems?oslc.where=dcterms%3Acontributor{foaf%3Aname="Diane"}&oslc.properties=dcterms:contributor&oslc.prefix=dcterms=%3Chttp%3A//purl.org/dc/terms/%3E&oslc.pageSize=1`

**Mimicking People-Search Concept always claims no knowledge "assetType":**
`https://<host>/ccm/oslc/contexts/<keything>/workitems?oslc.where=rtc_ext:assetType{dc:title="MyType"}&oslc.properties=rtc_ext:assetType&oslc.prefix=dcterms=%3Chttp%3A//purl.org/dc/terms/%3E&oslc.pageSize=1`

**Querying the Enum Seems to do nothing but return all options of the enum:**
`https://<host>/ccm/oslc/enumerations/<keything>/assetType?oslc.where=dc%3Atitle="MyType"&oslc.prefix=dcterms=%3Chttp%3A//purl.org/dc/terms/%3E`